# Scroll in first table cell to center

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift

I have a UITableView with custom cells. The cells are of a constant height 200. I want to animate the scrolling in of the first cell. This works using `scrollToRowAtIndexPath`. However, the row appears at the top of the view, whereas I would like it to appear dead center in the visible tableView. I tried setting the tableView's `contentInset` property to a bunch of different values, but none seem to provide the right offset. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your contentInset would be the height of the tableview divided by two minus half the height of the tableViewCell I would think. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Emil, I'm not sure what you mean. contentInset is of type UIEdgeInsets, so it takes a top, bottom, left, and right value. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeah, so the top inset would then be half the tableView-height minus half the cell height.

Answer (score 2):

`UITableView` actually has a neat method for this:

```
- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
              atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition
                      animated:(BOOL)animated
```

You can use it to scroll the tableView to the point where the cell is at the center of the tableView like this:

```
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:TRUE];
```

Comment: this does not work. Scrolling to the index at row 0 puts that cell at the top, even if I specify ScrollPositionMiddle.

Comment: That's expected behaviour, since there are no cells above it, the scroll view starts at the first cell, and it cannot be scrolled further up. To achieve the effect you want, you'll have to use an inset, see my comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could find to do this was to use `scrollRectToVisible` instead of `scrollToRowAtIndexPath`. For whatever reason (possibly because scrolling on my table was disabled), the positioning was still off even using @Emil's suggestion of combining `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` with a `contentInset`.

This works:

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: cellHeight, left: 0, bottom: cellHeight, right: 0)
tableView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRectMake(0, 0 - tableView.contentSize.height, cellWidth, tableView.contentSize.height), animated: false)
```